# How to search for array of string in each row of another column and get the count in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a excel with a column Address and another lookup column(List) containing list of lookup strings:-

| Address |  |  | List |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| St Dunstans Street; Waterlooville; PO7 5YT; United Kingdom |  |  | London |
| Simone Weil Avenue; Week; EX18 0DJ; United Kingdom |  |  | Whitehill |
| Greyfriars Road; Carbrooke; IP25 8PW; United Kingdom |  |  | Southampton |
| Terrick Rd; Elham; CT4 9GQ; United Kingdom |  |  | Jameston |
| Earls Avenue; Whitehill; ME13 2QW; United Kingdom |  |  | United Kingdom |
| Cheriton Rd; West Newton; HU11 7LB; United Kingdom |  |  |  |
| Marlborough Crescent; Southampton; SO15 4JL; United Kingdom |  |  |  |
| Baldock Street; Newton; ML12 6PZ; United Kingdom |  |  |  |

I want to search for all the strigns in List in Address column and return the count of strings matching
What I want to achieve :-

| Address | Count_Flag |  | List |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| St Dunstans Street; Waterlooville; PO7 5YT; United Kingdom | 1 |  | London |
| Simone Weil Avenue; Week; EX18 0DJ; United Kingdom | 1 |  | Whitehill |
| Greyfriars Road; Carbrooke; IP25 8PW; United Kingdom | 1 |  | Southampton |
| Terrick Rd; Elham; CT4 9GQ; United Kingdom | 1 |  | Jameston |
| Earls Avenue; Whitehill; ME13 2QW; United Kingdom | 2 |  | United Kingdom |
| Cheriton Rd; West Newton; HU11 7LB; United Kingdom | 1 |  |  |
| Marlborough Crescent; Southampton; SO15 4JL; United Kingdom | 2 |  |  |
| Baldock Street; Newton; ML12 6PZ; United Kingdom | 1 |  |  |

I tried something like this :

```
=--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(@$D$2:$D$6,A2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=SUM(--ISNUMBER(FIND("; "&D$2:D$6&";","; "&A2&";")))
```

Or if you don't have ms365, then use `SUMPRODUCT()` isntead of `SUM()`.

Note that the concatenated semi-colons are there to prevent false positive matches. Drag down the formula.

Answer (score 1):

**You can simply use this formula as shown in image below**

**Formula Used In Cell B2**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$2:$D$6,$A2)))
```

**Break Down Of Each Function Used In The Formula:-**

```
SEARCH($D$2:$D$6,$A2)
```

***The SEARCH function returns the position of one text string inside another. SEARCH returns the location of the first character of find_text inside within_text. Unlike FIND, SEARCH allows wildcards, and is not case-sensitive.***

```
{#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;45}
```

**This is what it return when you select and press F9, i.e. the position**

**Next, we need to check whether its a number or not, so we use the below**

```
ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$2:$D$6,$A2))
```

**And Returns an array of TRUE's And FALSE's**

```
{FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE}
```

**To Convert the same into `BOOLEAN` VALUES we use double negative which coerces TRUE or FALSE values to their numeric equivalents, 1 and 0**

```
--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$2:$D$6,$A2))
```

**The above converts to 1 & 0**

```
{0;0;0;0;1}
```

**Now we can simply wrap the whole within SUMPRODUCT to get the counts**

[image: SUMPRODUCT]

Answer (score 0):

You may try wildcard using with `COUNTIFS()` function.

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A9,"*"&C2&"*")
```

[image]